# prestashop 1.6 homefeatured cathgory not shown on frontpanel

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When loading the prestashop 1.6 site mastercubestore.dk, the homefeatured cathegory is not loaded on front.
When jeg press the different link and goes back to news then it shows up´.
How can i overcome this

Comment: the site is not available

Comment: Sorry www.mastercubestore.dk is the right link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pane you want open by default needs to have an "active" class too. In you case that would be `<ul id="blocknewproducts">` just add the active class to that element and it should be shown on page load

Comment: Tank you i Found an error in ny Theame header.tpl file